# Archlinux on Cubieboard2 Nand

Tags: arm, embedded, archlinux-arm

I would know if there is the possibile to migrate the operating system installed on SD to the Nand of the Cubieboard2.
I have followed the official guide at [enter link description here](https://archlinuxarm.org/platforms/armv7/allwinner/cubieboard-2) for install it on SD.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can it boot from another USB device? it would make things much easier, boot from usb, and do something like `dd if=/dev/sdcard of=/dev/internalstorage`

Comment: Ok, but I don't be able to find the /dev/nand device... using other OS like cubiez, the nand device is visible.

Comment: You should, looking at [this guide](http://linux-sunxi.org/Cubieboard/Installing_on_NAND) It could be `/dev/nanda` and `/dev/nandb`, or `/dev/nand1` and `/dev/nand2`

Comment: [This is another guide](https://github.com/cubieplayer/cubian/wiki/Install-Cubian)

Comment: Hi LPs, this guide seems to be for Cubian only... in Archlinux system on SD there isn't any device named nandX in /dev... Can I enable it in the kernel? If yes how can I do this?

Comment: I'm not an Cubieboard2 expert. Linux talking, if you have a recente kernel, you can surely enable it by dtb, but I'm quite sure, as I found out stuff for Cubian, you can find out infos for Archlinux (that I don't know what is it).